# ¿Cómo puedo quitar las filas duplicadas?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

¿Cuál es la mejor manera para quitar las filas duplicadas de una tabla bastante grande? (Por ejemplo de más de 300.000 filas)

Por supuesto, las filas no serán duplicados perfectos debido a la existencia de un campo de identidad `ROWID`

```
MyTable
-----------
RowID int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
Col1 varchar(20) not null,
Col2 varchar(2048) not null,
Col3 tinyint not null
```

> Pregunta original: [How can I remove duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

Comment: Estimado lo invito a que lea información sobre preguntas traducidas ubicadas en  http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/14/son-aceptables-las-traducciones-directas-de-respuestas-de-stackoverflow-en-ingl

Comment: Hola use la opción 2 que das y me sirvió perfectamente, gracias por tu aporte!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Primero que nada, necesitas decidir cual será tu criterio de duplicidad. Por ejemplo, yo deseo evaluar
si la segunda (col1) y tercera (col2) columna en conjunto se repite.

Primero data de prueba

```
insert into MyTable
values (1,4533660,1,'COMPANY 1')
insert into MyTable
values (2,4533660,1,'COMPANY 1')
insert into MyTable
values (3,954189547,1,'COMPANY 2')
insert into MyTable
values (4,954189547,1,'COMPANY 2')
insert into MyTable
values (5,3652591,1,'COMPANY 3')
insert into MyTable
values (6,4201580,1,'COMPANY 4')
insert into MyTable
values (7,3337788,1,'COMPANY 5')
```

Luego la consulta para obtener los duplicados en base al criterio predefinido.

```
Select 
Col1,
Col2,
COUNT(*)
from MyTable 
group by Col1,
Col2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Con esta consulta, fácilmente puedes encontrar los duplicados, más importante que la 
consulta en sí, es el criterio que uses.

Si deseas eliminar la data duplicada (obviamente recomendado realizar un backup o encapsular
todo en una transacción), puedes realizar lo siguiente:

```
DELETE A
FROM MyTable A 
INNER JOIN 
(
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY a.col1,
        a.Col2
        ORDER BY a.Col1,a.Col2)AS POS,
        a.rowID,
        a.Col3
        FROM MyTable A
        JOIN 
        (
            Select 
            Col1,
            Col2,
            COUNT(*) AS CONTADOR
            from MyTable 
            group by Col1,
            Col2
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        ) TB
        ON A.col1 = TB.col1
        AND A.col2 = TB.col2
) TB_2
ON
a.ROWID = tb_2.ROWID 
and tb_2.pos > 1
```

Comment: Cómo se debe modificar la consulta para mantener el último RowID de cada uno y eliminar los demás?, no mantener el primer registro como se define en el anterior ejemplo

Comment: @LuisaRestrepo, ordénalo por el criterio q desees para que el que tú dices que es el último row se vuelva el primero y así no tengas que hacer cambio en la consulta.

Comment: lo que hice fue agregar el contador en el query interno " ...POS, a.rowID,      a.Col3,TB.CONTADOR ...", y luego modifiqué la condición "tb_2.pos > 1" por "and tb_2.CONTADOR <> tb_2.pos", lo que eliminaría los registros diferentes al último contador.

Comment: @LuisaRestrepo, si te funcionó excelente, me alegra que el post te haya servido :)

Answer (score 3):

tomando en cuenta de que la duplicidad ocurrira en las demas columnas y de que existe una columna que si sera diferente (RowID) unicamente seria de enumerar con la función ROW_NUMBER, particionado por todas las columnas excepto RowID y eliminar aquellos registros en cuyo caso la numeración sea > 1, no se si es la mejor forma pero esta sería una opción:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
  WHERE RowID IN (SELECT RowID 
                    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Col1,Col2,Col3 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS R_ID,RowID,Col1,Col2,Col3
                            FROM MyTable) a
                   WHERE R_ID > 1)
```

La siguiente forma también fuciona, y útil de usar en caso de que no se tenga alguna columna para diferenciar los registros (en el caso que indicas se tenia a RowId). Pero no se si depende de la versión del SQL Server, a mi me ha funcionado en SQL Server 2012:

```
WITH FUENTE AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Col1,Col2,Col3 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS R_ID,Col1,Col2,Col3
  FROM MyTable) DELETE FROM FUENTE WHERE R_ID > 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Una opción es usar tablas temporales. Para ello:

1. Crea una tabla temporal que tendrá las filas no duplicadas.
2. Inserta todas las filas no duplicadas en la tabla temporal.
3. Borra todos los registros de la tabla original.
4. Vuelca la tabla temporal en la tabla original.
5. Opcionalmente, elimina la tabla temporal (se borrará automáticamente al final de la sesión).

El código (no lo he probado) sería algo así:

```sql
-- Los puntos 1 y 2 se podrían hacer en un solo paso: crear tabla temporal e insertar datos
INSERT INTO #tablaTemporal
SELECT DISTINCT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM   MyTable;

-- Borrar todos los datos de la tabla original
DELETE FROM MyTable;

-- Volcar los datos no duplicados desde la tabla temporal a la original
INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT * FROM #tablaTemporal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigos: Les adjunto una Transact que desarrollé y que funciona sin tablas adicionales. Yo no elimino las filas duplicadas, pero cambiando la línea de Update por otra de Delete se puede lograr

```
Declare @Fecha Date, @Liquidacion Int, @IdPersonal Int;
DECLARE CN CURSOR FOR
SELECT Fecha, Liquidacion, IdPersonal FROM Personal_tarjas
Where IdPersonal = 9
GROUP BY Fecha, Liquidacion, IdPersonal
HAVING count(*) > 1 And IdPersonal <> 0
OPEN CN;
    FETCH NEXT FROM CN Into @Fecha, @Liquidacion, @IdPersonal;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  Begin
    WHILE (Select Count(*) From Personal_tarjas Where Fecha = @Fecha And 
Liquidacion = @Liquidacion And IdPersonal = @IdPersonal AND IdPersonal = 9) > 1
    BEGIN
        Update Top(1) Personal_tarjas Set IdPersonal = 0 Where Fecha = @Fecha 
And Liquidacion = @Liquidacion And IdPersonal = @IdPersonal AND IdPersonal = 9;
        If (Select Count(*) From Personal_tarjas Where Fecha = @Fecha And 
Liquidacion = @Liquidacion And IdPersonal = @IdPersonal AND IdPersonal = 9) <= 1
            BREAK;
        Else
            CONTINUE;
    END;
    FETCH NEXT FROM CN Into @Fecha, @Liquidacion, @IdPersonal;
  End
  CLOSE CN;
  DEALLOCATE CN;
```

Espero les sirva.
Juan Carlos

Answer (score -1):

```
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.[ID],A.[NRO_SS] ORDER BY A.[ID],A.[NRO_SS] ) AS POS,*
        INTO #DM_TdeInterFallasDrive FROM [dbImport].[dbo].[DM_TdeInterFallasDrive] A

        DELETE FROM #DM_TdeInterFallasDrive WHERE POS > 1

        DROP TABLE [dbImport].[dbo].[DM_TdeInterFallasDrive]
        
        SELECT * INTO [dbImport].[dbo].[DM_TdeInterFallasDrive] FROM #DM_TdeInterFallasDrive

        DROP TABLE #DM_TdeInterFallasDrive

        ALTER TABLE [dbImport].[dbo].[DM_TdeInterFallasDrive]
        DROP COLUMN POS
    
        SELECT * FROM [dbImport].[dbo].[DM_TdeInterFallasDrive]
```

Comment: Agrega por favor una descripción de lo que realiza tu publicación por favor.